# Should I use unowned self in the websocket close completion handler?

Tags: swift, websocket, memory-leaks, closures, vapor

I have a Vapor Swift App which uses WebSockets. I have a closure that fires on close of the WebSocket and does something with the WebSocket object that has been closed.

```swift
app.webSocket("route") { _, socket in

    // do I have to use [unowned socket] here?

    socket.onClose.whenComplete { /* [unowned socket] */ _ in
        removeFromWhatever(socket)
    }
}
```

As I understand `[unowned self]` should be used if a closure on an object captures self. In this case the onClose is a property of the WebSocket and the whenComplete closure is a method of the onClose object and the closure captures the WebSocket object.

This is especially interesting because the onText callback of the WebSocket object provides a WebSocket as an argument to prevent memory leaks.

```swift
socket.onText { socket /* passed in to pervent memory leaks */, string in
    socket.send(string.reversed())
}
```

Do I need to use `[unowned socket]` in the onClose closure in this case? Can a memory leak happen if I don't use `[unowned socket]`?

Comment: "if a closure on an object captures self." This is only an issue if the closure is strongly referenced by `self` (directly or indirectly). Using weak would break that strong retain cycle. I advise people to learn when to use `weak` by first learning about strong retain cycles, understanding how they happen, and what they mean. It really takes the guesswork out of "should I use weak here?"

Comment: @Alexander - Reinstate Monica but the closure set on the close callback which is set on the WebSocket element and the closure references the same WebSocket element... isn't this a strong retain cycle?